# Can't run Lucene++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Anyone tried to run [LucenePlusPlus](https://github.com/luceneplusplus/LucenePlusPlus)?

I was able to compile and install; but I don't know how to run it.

In the documentation page I see:

> To run the demos section and indexfiles.exe directory to index
>   directory to store index and searchfiles.exe -index directory you
>   stored the index in

But no indication on how to use it in Unix systems.

Comment: what do you mean by saying run it?

Comment: I mean, how its used in ubuntu. In the documentation page I see  **To run the demos** section and _indexfiles.exe <directory to index> <directory to store index>_ and _searchfiles.exe -index <directory you stored the index in>_. But no indication on how to use it in unix systems